# How do I retrieve a Video by ID with Youtube API v3?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, google-client

I'd like to get a Response referring to a single Video on Youtube. Let's say that I know its ID and like to see if it is still on Youtube. How does the request have to look like?

I am using the google-api-client with client_id and client_secret and like to do something like this:

> client.execute(
>     :api_method => youtube.search.list, 
>     :parameters => {:id => my_video_id, :part => 'id,snippet' })

It just returns me a Set of default Video Data. It is unlikely, that this is a matter of authentication, because uploading and deleting videos works fine. But for this purpose I can't find the right way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the youtube API but the api_method suggests that it will return a list. Pehaps you should have a better look in the documentation to find a more suitable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with the [videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) instead.

```
client.execute( :api_method => youtube.videos.list, :parameters => {:id => my_video_id, :part => 'id,snippet' })
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping, that it would be that simple. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome... Do you know how I can get shares and view count from this video object?