# Youtube Data API v3 - Search videos by using comma-separated video Ids

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to search for videos based solely on their ID via comma-separated string of video IDs. It's feasible, the API Explorer provides a sample with comma-separated IDs via...

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&
id=JFex915ZebY%2CVGvHnDeS12o%2CYxHnNdZMngk&key={YOUR_API_KEY} // %2C = comma
```

...but nothing on how to display in friendly GUI format (dang!). With one ID the code below works, but with more than one ID all fails. Am wondering what must I add/modify to make the following code sample work? I'm getting this error in console:

**TypeError: response.items is undefined**

```
. . .

function searchvideo(vq, pageToken) {
$('ol').empty();
gapi.client.setApiKey('API-KEY');
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function(){
var vIDquery = $('#ytquery').val();

var vrequestOptions = { // Anything missing here?
q: vIDquery,
part: 'snippet'
};

. . .

var vrequest = gapi.client.youtube.search.list(vrequestOptions);

vrequest.execute(function(response) {

. . .

(TypeError: response.items is undefined)

for(var i=0;i<response.items.length;i++) {
var rvideoID = response.items[i].id.videoId; // or snippet.videoId
var rchannelID = response.items[i].snippet.channelId;
var rchannelTitle = response.items[i].snippet.channelTitle;
var rTitle = response.items[i].snippet.title;
var rDescription = response.items[i].snippet.description;
var rthumbnail = response.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

. . .
```

Kinda noob here with API v3, still trying to grasp the new stuff, looks like items.length thingy may be the culprit, am I missing an array? Any hints would be greatly appreciated, Thx. - Koolness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, while answering other questions, I fell on this one:
[How do I retrieve a Video by ID with Youtube API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857970/how-do-i-retrieve-a-video-by-id-with-youtube-api-v3)

I just needed to specify correctly the required parameters, I swear I tried them all LOL!

Specific code looks like this now:

```
. . .

function searchvideo(vIDquery, pageToken) {
$('ol').empty();
gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR-API-KEY');
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function(){
var vIDquery = $('#ytquery').val(); // Video Id input box

var requestOptions = {
id: vIDquery, // Changed q: to id:
part: 'id,snippet' // Changed 'snippet' to 'id,snippet'
};

. . .

// Changed youtube.search.list to youtube.videos.list

var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list(requestOptions);

. . .
```

In Data API v2, I had to code a complex method to override error responses so that the gdata call wouldn't fail if finding a missing or mispelled ID. I also had to cope with unordered video lists which had to be reordered with array apply-done methods. Now I see API 3 works marvels without code bloat! Awesomeness!

Hope this Helps others. - Koolness